# unable to select packages update (no such package required by: world[update]

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am new to Docker, I am just starting to learn Docker.

--- Docker file ---

```
# use an existing docker image as a base
FROM alpine 

# download and install dependency
RUN apk add -- update redis

# tell the image what to do when it starts as a container
CMD ["redis-server"]
```

I navigated to the directory as same as the docker file and then ran the command

```
docker build .
```

When I run this command, suddenly i got this error message

```
> Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB Step 1/3 : FROM alpine
> ---> b2aa39c304c2 Step 2/3 : RUN apk add -- update redis  ---> Running in a695bae9b0e1 fetch
> https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
> fetch
> https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
> ERROR: unable to select packages:   update (no such package):
>     required by: world[update] The command '/bin/sh -c apk add -- update redis' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Dont know how to resolve this

Comment: Do you mean `--update` as a single option, with no space?  (Why not run the [Docker Hub `redis` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis) instead of trying to build your own?)

Comment: solved the issue by removing space ( --update ) in the docker file